# doing unpaid overtime during internship

Tags: salary, internship, overtime, singapore

I am currently doing my internship. I am working office hours from 8:30am till 5:30pm.

My company doesn't pay any overtime pay. There have been two or so days where I was told that I needed to work late until 10pm or 11pm. I told my manager that I cannot work late, and he replied that is not acceptable as it's a crucial week. We are doing a project which will go live for public use on a particular day. Those two days of overtime are a few days before the live day.

Is this considered to be normal, and what rights do I have as an intern?

Comment: If you agree to stay late then will you be allowed to come in late the next day or week?

Comment: Are there any other interns in your organisation?  Are they also being asked to stay late?  Be aware that you probably can refuse, but they probably can refuse to extend your probation.  While it shouldn't happen, it's common enough for deadlines to require an extra push if they can't be moved.  Good employers will give you back the extra time in lieu if you have had to work extra to meet a deadline.

Comment: @Brandin I did not agree to it tho. I didnt ask about coming in late the next day. Less likely hood will i be allowed to come late.

Comment: @JaneS noope. just me alone. I tried to say that i cant stay late tho. but seems that im still needed to stay and work late

Comment: @MrGonzalez Please be next to other users

Answer (score 0):

Based on the culture in Asia, working late is often expected.  It really comes down to if you are planning on working at that company in the future.  If you don't really care about this company then by all means you can go home at the time you want.

Even while saying that, you could be able to convince your boss depending on your explanation of *why* you cannot work late.  If there is a medical need or something along those lines, you may be approved.

Answer (score 0):

I only have one question, is it paid internship ? If not tell them to back off as you said you'll be living soon. If it is paid then tell them that you won't work if unpaid as it's the rule, you work for them, they pay you for the work you've done, period. I think that being an intern is not really relevant here.